# MIPS - Array in array index

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mips32

What is the following C code in MIPS?

```c
f = A[B[i]]
```

I'm told it can be done in 6 lines but can't quite figure out how. 
`f` is in `$t0`, `i` is in `$t3`, `A[]` is in `$s0`, and `B[]` is in `$s1`.  All types are integer.

The best I am able to think of is

```mips
lw $t5, $t3($s0);  # Doesn't work because lw syntax doesn't accept a register as an offset
lw $t6, $t5($s1);
sadd $t0, $t6, $zero
```

Obviously this is wrong. How would i go about getting the correct offset for each line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be more efficient ways, but here's one way in 6 lines:

```
sll $t2,$t3,2    # t2 = i * sizeof(int)
addu $t2,$t2,$s1 # t2 = &B[i]
lw $t0,0($t2)    # t0 = B[i]
sll $t0,$t0,2    # t0 *= sizeof(int)
addu $s0,$s0,$t0 # s0 = &A[B[i]]
lw $t0,0($s0)    # t0 = A[B[i]]
```

Read a [MIPS instruction set reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) to get more information about what individual instructions do.

Comment: Wow that makes incredible sense now. Thank you very much.